# In Being and Time, was Heidegger doing phenomenology, using the phenomenological reduction?

Tags: heidegger, phenomenology, being-and-time, husserl

In Being and Time, was Heidegger doing phenomenology, using the [phenomenological reduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/phen-red/)? If so, how routinely, or even when?

Comment: to my mind, he does not do so to convincingly say that the meaning of Being is a relevant question

Comment: Heidegger more or less rejects phenomenological reduction in its Husserlian form, indeed it is the start of the road that leads to the abstraction of the "transcendental ego". The kind of neutral detached position that Husserl tries to achieve by his reduction is anathema to Heidegger's exploration of "thrownness", it detaches from the very being he is after. You can look at Seeburger's attempts to find some place for the reduction in [Heidegger and the Phenomenological Reduction](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2107054), and at [Russell's recent survey](https://philarchive.org/archive/RUSPRI).

Comment: thanks, that's a v helpful comment @Conifold shame it won't generate any answers